# I am going bonkers with this one simple SQL question

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Input table:

| STAGE_NO | STAGE_ENTERED_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-12-01 14:16:47 |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | null |
| 6 | 2017-02-12 0:00:00 |
| 7 | 2017-12-12 0:00:00 |

I want a new column that will give me the next stage_no where "stage_entered_date" is not-null.

This is the result that I am expecting:

| STAGE_NO | STAGE_ENTERED_DATE | Next_Stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-12-01 14:16:47 | 6 |
| 1 | null | 6 |
| 2 | null | 6 |
| 3 | null | 6 |
| 4 | null | 6 |
| 5 | null | 6 |
| 6 | 2017-02-12 0:00:00 | 7 |
| 7 | 2017-12-12 0:00:00 | null |

Disclaimer: Next_Stage column means next_stage where date is not null.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Please don't insert images of data/code; instead insert it into your answer (and format it clearly)

Comment: Hi @Shru, ideally you should include some information about the attempts that you've made to achieve your expected outcome - that way people can help you to understand where you're potentially going astray in your existing thinking

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the lead window function, ignoring nulls, and redefining nulls as the null in a different column using the IFF function:

```
with T1 as
(
    select 
    COLUMN1::int as "STAGE_NO",
    COLUMN2::timestamp as "STAGE_ENTERED_DATE"
    from (values
    ('0','2015-12-01 14:16:47'),
    ('1',null),
    ('2',null),
    ('3',null),
    ('4',null),
    ('5',null),
    ('6','2017-02-12 0:00:00'),
    ('7','2017-12-12 0:00:00')
    )
)
select   STAGE_NO
        ,STAGE_ENTERED_DATE
        ,lead(iff(STAGE_ENTERED_DATE is not null, STAGE_NO, null)) 
           ignore nulls over (partition by null order by STAGE_NO) as NEXT_STAGE
from T1
;
```

| STAGE_NO | STAGE_ENTERED_DATE | NEXT_STAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-12-01 14:16:47.000000000 | 6 |
| 1 | null | 6 |
| 2 | null | 6 |
| 3 | null | 6 |
| 4 | null | 6 |
| 5 | null | 6 |
| 6 | 2017-02-12 00:00:00.000000000 | 7 |
| 7 | 2017-12-12 00:00:00.000000000 | null |

This will perform the stage calculation across the entire table. You probably have something like a customer, company, or some other "thing" that goes through these stages. You can specify what that is using a partition by clause in the window function. It's currently set to null, but you can simply change it to the column that defines the sets of rows for the phases.